# Firefox downloads images twice

Tags: firefox

If I save any image that Firefox has already downloaded, it starts downloading the image again, which is dumb and a waste of bandwidth.

Is there a way to prevent this? I'm using FF version 33.

Answer (score 0):

The Image Picker Add-On will do this.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-picker/

Once enabled, it will cache images on first download, then it will download from the cache on all future downloads.

It also has a few other features you might like.

Cheers!

Sources: Personal Experience

Comment: Is there a specific configuration setting I need to tweak? Because it's not fixing the problem I have.